# Plain text converts to link on mobile

Tags: html, href, newsletter

I have a name like this Domain.com, in my normal e-mail account it will be displayed as plain text but at my mobile it's a link.

Is it possible to disabble it by a tag?

Comment: Note sure what you are doing cause we need more code to help you, if it's a site you are viewing, are you making a html email or something but either way.
I think what you want is:
use a style (css) of `text-decoration: none` that will remove link underline.

Comment: I have just a plain text in email, like Travel.com, and my mobile displays it like a link.

Comment: Which mobile browser(s) are you talking about? This seems to be an oddity in some Mac software. There appears to be discussions on disabling the (mis)behavior in the software but not on preventing it when sending HTML e-mail (which is what you are doing, right?). Try putting some zero-width character after the dot, e.g. `Domain.&#xfeff;com` to defeat the “smart” behavior. (Unfortunately, it would then cause problems in copy & paste.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the email client adding the link afterwards. Trick is to make it unrecognizable so that it isn't triggered.

[This article](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices) addresses the issue.

If you are not building a full html email (no style tag), you might be able to get away with adding a zero width space `&#65279;` in the domain to help break it up. Something like this might work:

```
http:/&#65279;/domain.&#65279;com
```